# I want to use redis as a lru cache, can I do it per db or do I need new a redis instance?

Tags: redis, lru

I want to use current redis instance as lru cache.
However, I'm already using db0 for expiration keys.

Is there a possibility to use current redis instance as a lru cache (with different db number for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible and there is nothing inherently wrong with the idea. To answer more precisely, I'd need more details about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may use your current `Redis` instance to function as LRU cache.
Config would be applied to the whole instance and not any specific database.

If you update your existing configuration for LRU, your db0 would also be affected. If this is not what you want to do, create another instance.